# Invalid Argument, Not sure why

Tags: c#, invalid-argument

**Here is a bit of my code.**

```
drawingContext.DrawEllipse(this.handOpenBrush, null, handPosition, HandSize, HandSize);
```

That code works fine.

Though, as soon as I do this, I get the errors that it has some invalid arguments.

```
drawingContext.DrawEllipse(this.handOpenBrush, null, (handPosition.Offset(20,20)), HandSize, HandSize);
```

All I am doing is offsetting the handPosition point by (20,20). I do not see what I could of done to cause the program to all of  sudden have argument errors.

Comment: What language and API are you using (is it actually C# as Anthony's edit guesses)? It's going to be hard for you to get help if you make us guess. Also, what sort of "errors?" Are these compilation errors, errors at runtime? What's the actual *text* of the error?

Comment: Look at what `Point.Offset` returns (or more to the point what it _doesn't_ return)

Comment: looking at your 'This Code Works fine` pline it's only common sense that `handPosition.OffSet` is causing an error can you show all relevant code perhaps you're putting `(handPosition.Offset(20,20))` there is no need for the first `(`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Point.Offset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.point.offset(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't return a new point - it *mutates* the existing `Point`.  So you need to either mutate the point *before* making the call to `DrawEllipse`:

```
handPosition.Offset(20,20);
drawingContext.DrawEllipse(this.handOpenBrush, null, handPosition, HandSize, HandSize);
```

or use a method that *does* return a new `Point`:

```
drawingContext.DrawEllipse(this.handOpenBrush, null, Point.Add(handPosition, new Vector(20,20)), HandSize, HandSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

`handPosition` is a `Point`.

`Point.Offset()` is a method returning void, not a `Point`, therefore the argument is invalid.

Instead, call `handPosition.Offset(20,20)` before the `drawingContext.DrawEllipse()` call, and you can then still pass `handPosition` in as the third argument.